# add user meta for featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a site in which a user is able to capture his/her pic(via .getusermedia) which updated as the post thumbnail.

The problem is that the post thumbnail gets updated for all users - I want the post thumbnail to be updated only for that particular user

```
function Generate_Featured_Image( $filename, $parent_post_id  ){
    require('/wp-load.php');

    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename(  $filename ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename(     $filename ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename,  $parent_post_id );

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    //add_user_meta( $current_user_id, $parent_post_id, $attach_id);
    set_post_thumbnail( $parent_post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

script.php

```
Generate_Featured_Image( $addroot.$current_user_id.$extimage, 88  );
// addroot=path ext-extension(.jpg) (this is name of file saved)
```

i tried to user add_user_meta to accomplish the task but couldn't even get a start

**UPDATE**

```
<?php 
// $filename is succesfully saved as currentuserid+.jpg.
 $addroot = '/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/';


  $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();


$extimage = '.jpg';


$filename = $addroot.$current_user_id.$extimage;

 $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

 // Get the path to the upload directory.
 $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

 // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
 $attachment = array(
'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
'post_content'   => '',
'post_status'    => 'inherit'
  );

// Insert the attachment.
 $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, 0 );

 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

  // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
      wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
     update_user_meta( get_the_ID(), $filename , $_POST[ $filename ] );
  ?>
```

how to proceed further by calling the image to by $attach_id from usermeta and displayinf it to user as thumbnail- unable to figure this step

Comment: Is post where thumbnail should get updated one and the same for every user? And why set it as post thumbnail and not some user meta field?

Comment: yes the post is same i.e post id is same for all users. i just want different featured image for the same post for different users(as uploaded by them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really set a different featured image for post based on a user. There is just one post, therefore only one featured image for it.
If you want to display a different image, based on which user is viewing the post, save that use `wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, 0)` to insert attachment without binding it to the post. Then save that `$attach_id` to the `usermeta` table. Then, when user is viewing that post, simply get `$attach_id` with `get_user_meta` and display that image (you can use [`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/) for example) instead of featured image of the post.

**UPDATE**
First, saving user meta should look like this

```
update_user_meta($current_user_id, '_avatar_id', $attach_id);
```

Second, in the beginning, you should check if user is logged in with [`is_user_logged_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function.

Third, you should check for user had avatar before and remove it (I mean, why store their old one after they have a new one, right?) like so:

```
$old_attach=get_user_meta($current_user_id, '_avatar_id', true);
if(is_numeric($old_attach))
{
    wp_delete_attachment($old_attach, true);
}
```

Your final code to save avatar should look like:

```
if (is_user_logged_in())
{
    $addroot = '/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/';
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $extimage = '.jpg';
    $filename = $addroot . $current_user_id . $extimage;
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename),
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, 0);
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename));
    $old_attach = get_user_meta($current_user_id, '_avatar_id', true);
    if (is_numeric($old_attach))
    {
        wp_delete_attachment($old_attach, true);
    }
    update_user_meta($current_user_id, '_avatar_id', $attach_id);
}
else
{
    //show error here or something   
}
```

Now, to access it, you can write a simple function, like this:

```
function get_user_avatar()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $avatar_id = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), '_avatar_id', true);
        if (is_numeric($avatar_id))
        {
            return'<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url($avatar_id) . '"  alt="User avatar"/>';
        }
        else
        {
            return '<img src="url_to_your_default_avatar" alt="User avatar"/>';
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it's important to bind the image to post there are some 700 posts altogether.

Comment: @AviSangray well, like I said, you can't bind different image for the same post base on user. Perhaps you need to rethink you logic with this.

Comment: i got what you meant. maybe i should setup to create a new post with limited visibility for each user after upload.

Comment: just struck my mind. do you have any link to the working/code of avatar of users in wordpress.

Comment: I've described steps in my answer. You just have but to adapt your current code. Except, before setting new avatar, you might want to check if user has any attachment (his current avatar) and remove it.

Comment: i'm stuck at figuring out the code for your answer. could you help me out?

Comment: i'm using this for post not for avatar

Comment: @AviSangray Call it whatever you want, it does what you want it to do, doesn't it?

Comment: i added the function to call successfully but unable to invoke to show up in post images . my php ain't that good

Comment: please do reply to my query. meanwhile i'm trying to modify post thumbnail functions in post.php to use user meta image at post thumbnail

Comment: @AviSangray you're going about it in a wrong way. Instead of modifying core files, instead of calling function to get post thumbnail, call the one I wrote above

Comment: but i dont think it would work for multiple posts display on single page/category

Comment: You lost me. Is image for each post should be different for each user. In other words, same user can have different image for each post?

Comment: Yes user will capture an image and each post have different image after processing like grayscale, some frames on it, textured, texts etc.

Comment: @AviSangray well then, the idea is still pretty much the same, except for instead of single attach ID, you can save them as array (either serialized or json encoded) of pairs post id => attach id and call it when accessing the post. It just needs small changes to the current code, but you should be able to make them by yourself.

Comment: Yeah thats what im working on. Easy with the fact that all images has name of userid+postid.

Comment: well i did succeed in that there's another problem
currently i'm able to replace image on post image by using javascript changing img src to user meta image.
how could i do it on a page with multiple posts like a categories page
i just thought i need to get a way to find the post id and the related img src of the post id any help in this direction?

Comment: or alternatively how could i add an id tag to img src by default to post id or similar option in post editing page